# Is there any way to convert audio to text (speech recognition) in python without using any API(Google, google cloud, IBM,...etc)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pyaudio

I have to create a python project to convert audio to text using python , but i don't want to use any available API(Google,IBM..etc).
Is there any functions or methods available in python to do that.

Comment: Are you looking to build a speech to text API?

Comment: You want to build your own STT (speech-to-text) engine ??

Comment: @g10dras
Yes.........................

Comment: @John  Yes, I want to built an API on my own because I don't want to use any existing API.

Comment: That's a pretty huge project.  I'd start by looking at the literature to see how those companies built their APIs.  You're probably not going to get much useful info on stack overflow unless you narrow the scope of your question considerably.